# Swiper not working with Dynamic data in Framework7 with vue.js

Tags: vue.js, html-framework-7

I am using Framework7 swiper in my app. When I use static data then swiper works fine but it is not working when I fetch the data from the server using web service.
I have used DOM to update swiper but unfortunately, it is not updated. Please give me the solution to update the swiper.

My code is:

```
<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            posts: [],
        }
    },

    methods: {
        onF7Init:function() {
            this.theater();   
        },

        // function of fetch the data from serve:
        theater: function() {
            // fetch images path from server
            axios.get(`https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key={api_key}&primary_release_date.gte=2018-02-1&primary_release_date.lte=2018-02-21`)
                .then(response => {
                    current.**posts** = response.data.results;

                //I added this line to update the swiper:
                $$(this).find('#banner-swiper')[0].swiper.update();
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I added this line to update the swiper:

```
$$(this).find('#banner-swiper')[0].swiper.update()
```

My app template:

```
<f7-swiper pagination id="banner-swiper">

    <f7-swiper-slide  v-for="
     (post,index) in posts" :key="index" >              

         <img :src="'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' + 
            post.backdrop_path"/>
    </f7-swiper-slide>
</f7-swiper>
```

Comment: $$(this).find('#banner-swiper')[0].swiper.update(); is this placed in my-app.js ?

Comment: No, It is placed in Main.vue

Comment: I'm curious, what are those `**` for? Why are you not doing `this.posts` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following code to update your `swiper`.

```
this.$$(".swiper-container")[0].swiper.update();
```

If you are using more than 1 `swiper` in a single page then you can replace `[0]` with the index of your `swiper` or you can use Framework7 API to update your Swiper.

```
let swiper = this.$f7.swiper.get(".banner-swiper");
swiper.$el[0].swiper.update();
```

Both the solutions are working for me.

Comment: great @sagardhiman, if you have any issue let me know. I'll help you to sort out your problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of others who are finding this now,
the more elegant solution is to use `v-if` to ensure that the swiper is only initiated once you have the contents ready.

The slides not being updated with the dynamic data happens when the Swiper is created before you have your dynamic data ready.

You can add `v-if="posts.length > 0"` like so:

```
<f7-swiper pagination v-if="posts.length > 0" id="banner-swiper">

    <f7-swiper-slide  v-for="
     (post,index) in posts" :key="index" >              

         <img :src="'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' + 
            post.backdrop_path"/>
    </f7-swiper-slide>
</f7-swiper>
```